# Procedural grunge & scratches node set up with Voronoi Node 2.93

Tags: node-editor

Im following along a tutorial which was recorded in 2019, and the voronoi Node is different from the 2.93 Blender Im using. The result from the tutorial is significant different from what I'm getting. Can someone please see what my Node set up needs to get the same result at the tutorials?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-KO_qkM93q8

The red section is the instructors, and the blue section is mine.

Here is my file provided:

[image]

[image]

Comment: @RoyalSkies did a followup video showing what changed in 2.8.1 that should get you back on track: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F2edriq1PAQ

Comment: I totally missed that, thanks for the link, life saver!